# C# class to XML where a list of entries show up without "father property" node

Tags: c#, xml

Having the following example code:

```
public class MyHeader
{
    public string Identification { get; set; }
    public DateTime  Date { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public List<MyChild> Children { get; set; }
}

public class MyChild
{
    public string Identification { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public string GetXML()
    {
        var h = new MyHeader
        {
            Date = DateTime.Now,
            Description = "Something",
            Identification = "AAAAA11111",
            Children = new List<MyChild>
            {
                new MyChild { Identification = "B1", Description = "B1"},
                new MyChild { Identification = "B2", Description = "B2"},
                new MyChild { Identification = "B3", Description = "B3"}
            }
        };
        var xml = "";
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(h.GetType());
        using (var sww = new StringWriter())
        {
            using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(sww))
            {
                serializer.Serialize(writer, h);
                xml = sww.ToString();
            }
        }
        return xml;
    }
```

The result is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<MyHeader xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Identification>AAAAA11111</Identification>
    <Date>2020-09-09T11:55:04.2457349+02:00</Date>
    <Description>Something</Description>
    <Children>
        <MyChild>
            <Identification>B1</Identification>
            <Description>B1</Description>
        </MyChild>
        <MyChild>
            <Identification>B2</Identification>
            <Description>B2</Description>
        </MyChild>
        <MyChild>
            <Identification>B3</Identification>
            <Description>B3</Description>
        </MyChild>
    </Children>
</MyHeader>
```

Now the question: what is the easiest solution to produce the final XML without showing the `<Children>` node, but merging the children in the Header?

Result that I am looking for:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<MyHeader xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Identification>AAAAA11111</Identification>
    <Date>2020-09-09T11:55:04.2457349+02:00</Date>
    <Description>Something</Description>
    <MyChild>
        <Identification>B1</Identification>
        <Description>B1</Description>
    </MyChild>
    <MyChild>
        <Identification>B2</Identification>
        <Description>B2</Description>
    </MyChild>
    <MyChild>
        <Identification>B3</Identification>
        <Description>B3</Description>
    </MyChild>
</MyHeader>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an `XmlElementAttribute` above the list declaration:

```
[XmlElement(ElementName = "MyChild")]
public List<MyChild> Children { get; set; }
```

This will treat each child as its own item in the parent `MyHeader` object.

[Example](https://rextester.com/AAOFL47165)